# How to use BCP import for Chinese character (UTF-8)

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, bulkinsert, bcp

I have problem with using **BCP.exe** (Bulk Insert) for Chinese characters.

I have a file with a string of Chinese characters in it.

file : pp

image : file.png

I have a Table in SQL Server database with one column **nvarchar(1500)**.
Database collection is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**.

When I try to use Bulk Insert query to insert the data from file to database it works fine even without setting DATAFILETYPE or FORMATFILE.

images : bulk insert.png and bulk insert result.png

But when I try to use BCP.exe to import the same file to same table then I am getting wrong values in the table. I have tried different options like -w -N -n

Please find in the linked file what I have tried and what was the result.

[Files and pictures](https://mega.nz/#!g9RSCZYZ!S1cFfADoNH8YuB93x8gfu2-9tg4hu7JJ2-1SkPJz8Js)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQLServer 13.0 or higher the option -C 65001 might work.

-C is an option for specifying an encoding:

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#C)